# Why is this line not throwing an error: str strVariable = "text"

Tags: vba, excel, syntax-error

```
Str strTopLeftCellIdentifier = "Account No"
```

I just tracked down the cause of my code triggering the error handler. it was that line not updating the value of `strtopleftcellidentifier`. Obviously, the first `Str` isn't meant to be there.

Yet, it will run that line.

I'm aware that `Str()` is a VBA function, but even with that, I don't understand how it's interpreting that line in any intelligible way.

What does the macro think it's doing and/or why isn't it causing an error?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because `Str()` is a valid function name in VBA. So your statement is actually comparing `strTopLeftCellIdentifier` to `"Account No"` and passing the boolean result to `Str()`. It's the equivalent of:

```
Str False
```

And since you're not capturing the return value of `Str()`, parentheses are not required when making the call.

Comment: Thank you, that explains everything.